# How to deliver JSON over HTTP using Warp with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson, haskell-warp

I want to create a high-performance HTTP-based API running on Haskell using [warp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp) as a HTTP backend.

The server shall return JSON data upon request. This data shall be serialized by using [Aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html)

However, *warp* requires a response object whereas Aeson returns lazy `ByteString`s.

How can I tie both libraries together? For this question's scope I'm not interested in query parsing or routing, but in an example of how to tie both libraries together to deliver a correct JSON with correct headers.

*Note*: This question intentionally does not show any research effort, as it was answered Q&A-style-ish. See my answer if you require research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll build my example on the [HaskellWiki minimal warp example](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Servers).

For the sake of simplicity I removed any code like routing, replacing the most relevant parts by stubs and comments where to place what.

The JSON data we will serialize in this example is the list `["a","b","c"]`. The same response (= the JSON) will be returned for any URL.

The issue in connecting both libraries is that while *warp* requires a Blaze [`Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder-0.3.3.2/docs/Blaze-ByteString-Builder.html#t:Builder) to build its response properly, while *Aeson* returns (as you said) a lazy `ByteString`.
The appropriate function to connect both together is called [`fromLazyByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder-0.3.3.2/docs/Blaze-ByteString-Builder-ByteString.html#v:fromLazyByteString).

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder.ByteString (fromLazyByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BU

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    run port app

app :: Application
app req f = f $
    case pathInfo req of
        -- Place custom routes here
        _ -> anyRoute

-- The data that will be converted to JSON
jsonData = ["a","b","c"] :: [Text]

anyRoute = responseLBS
            status200
            [(hContentType, "application/json")]
            (encode jsonData)
```

**Update 05/01/2015:** Fix example for Warp/WAI 3.x

Comment: Note that wai provides a `responseLBS` function, which automatically adds the `fromLazyByteString` for you. It's also preferable to stick with the constructors in `Network.Wai` so you can avoid importing the `.Internal` module.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Thanks for noting that! I edited the code above to use `responseLBS`

Comment: @UliKöhler I get an error on the line `app req = return $` that says `Couldn't match type ‘Response’ with ‘IO ResponseReceived’
    Expected type: Application
      Actual type: Request`

Changing it to this works: `app req respond = respond $`

Comment: @CalvinCheng I believe this is related to API changes in WARP 3.x. I'll look into that within the next few days!

Comment: Because `Application` type expects a `request` argument as well as a `respond` argument?  Reference - http://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2015-01-04/wai-3.0.2.1/Network-Wai.html#t:Application

Comment: @CalvinCheng Basically the WAI maintainers changed it so instead of using `return`, you get a function `f` that you have to apply to the result. I edited that in the answer, it should work now. Please feel free to inform me in case you encounter any further issues.