# Handling HTTP GET Query parameters in Warp

Tags: http, haskell, query-string, haskell-warp

Using the warp HTTP server, I want to handle HTTP query parameters.

It's easy (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183489/2597135)) to make Warp render something for URLs like

```
http://localhost:3000/foo
```

How can I make it render

```
http://localhost:3000/foo?id=bar
```

in a way where the content is dependent on the `id` query parameter?

Additionally, how can I handle if there is no such parameter?

[How to deliver JSON over HTTP using Warp with Aeson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183489/2597135)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll build my example on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183490/2597135).

The most important module in this context it [`Network.HTTP.Types`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.3.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html), specifically the [`Query`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.3.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html#t:Query) type.

You can get a `Query` from a WAI `Request` using [`QueryString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-2.0.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:queryString).

As a `Query` is nothing more than a `[(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]`, we can use [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) from the base library to find the appropriate attribute.

However, as `lookup` wraps the type in a `Maybe` itself, we end up witha `Maybe (Maybe ByteString)`. My example contains the rather ugly-sounding function `maybeMaybeToMaybe` to convert this to a `Maybe ByteString`.

The example returns a plaintext response (on any URL) that contains the `id` query parameter. As it just uses `show`, for the example URL

```
http://localhost:3000/foo?id=bar
```

it yields

```
Query parameter: Just "foobar"
```

whereas for

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

it yields

```
Query parameter: Nothing
```

Here's the full source code:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Char.Utf8 (fromString)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    run port app

app req f = f $
    case pathInfo req of
        -- Place custom routes here
        _ -> anyRoute req

anyRoute req =
    let query = queryString req :: [(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]
        idParam = join $ lookup "id" query :: Maybe ByteString
    in responseBuilder
            status200
            [(hContentType, "text/plain")]
            $ fromString $ "Query parameter: " ++ (show idParam)
```

Comment: `maybeMaybeToMaybe` is just `Control.Monad.join`.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Thank you very much for noting this! I replaced `maybeMaybeToMaybe` by `join` in the code above, which made it a lot simpler! Also, I removed the internal import by using `responseBuilder`